# RaspberryPi 2 refuses to autologin

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I’m running raspbian on my RaspberryPi 2 and until yesterday it logged in automatically into `pi` on boot without any problem.

Today it didn’t. Luckily I had already changed root’s password so now I can log into that user.
I’d like to return using pi (which in `/etc/shadow` has an `*` in the password field and an `x`in `/etc/passwd`).

I’ve even checked in lightdm.conf and `autologin-user=pi` in not commented
I tried raspi-config->Boot Options->Desktop/CLI->Desktop autologin (the phrase next to ‘Desktop autologin’ even said ‘autologin as ‘pi’’

I don’t know what else I should try, could anybody help me?

**EDIT: RESOLVED. All I had to do was `sudo chown pi /home/pi/.Xauthority`**

Comment: Can you log in manually as `pi`?

Comment: No, I even tried modifying the password and then logging in, but it just keeps returning to the login screen after a few seconds of black screen

Answer (score 1):

> which in ‘/etc/shadow’ has an asterisk in the password field

I think this points to one of two situations although the first one I am not sure about:

1. There's an encrypted password in `/etc/passwd`.  This is pretty obvious, as it is a long string of random characters.  This seems to happen sometimes when `passwd` is run and not followed up with `pwconv` (it may be that it happens when `passwd` is run by a non-root user).  Ideally `pwconv` should be run, but the account should still work.
2. There's no encrypted password in `/etc/passwd`, meaning you have no password.  There's two variations on that, one in which you can login with no password -- the field in `/etc/passwd` in will be empty, nothing between two colons (`::`).

   The other variation is there's an x in the `/etc/passwd` password field (`:x:`).  In this case the significance of the asterisk in `/etc/shadow` is (from `man 5 shadow`):

   > encrypted password
   >
   > Refer to crypt(3) for details on how this string is interpreted.
   >
   > If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), **for instance ! or *,** the user will not be able to use a unix password to
   >          log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).

What you should try in the second case (it sounds like this is the problem, checking those two files would confirm it) is to run `passwd pi` as `root`, then (again as root) `pwconv`, check the two files again (there should be an `x` in the password field of `/etc/passwd`, and an encrypted string in `/etc/shadow`), and try logging in as user `pi`.

Presumably that is what is preventing the autologin, so once the manual login works it should too.

If all else fails you could also try removing the password field in `/etc/passwd` (leave just the two separator colons with nothing between).  You should now be able to log in without a password (just hit enter when asked).

Comment: I tried doing as you said, but both modifying the password and removing the ‘x’ in passwd, the situation hasn’t changed. It seems that it tries to log in but it fails, because when I enter the password, no error is displayed, the screen turns black for a few seconds and then it returns to the login screen

Comment: Sounds like something is going wrong with the GUI display manager. You should try from a console.  Use Ctrl-Alt-F[1-6] to find an open one without a GUI; there will be a plain text login there.  That should work, which will rule out an issue with the password, etc. -- if those files are set up correctly, a text login pretty must work, if it doesn't, you've done something wrong, try again.  Of course, know it is not actually a password issue won't fix the GUI.